# What is the meaning of this 'missing template arguments' C++ error

Tags: c++, templates

Ahh, C++ templates...

> The code I see,
>   makes sense to me,
>   but GCC...
>   it disagrees.

The following code compiles and runs as expected, but if you uncomment that `#define`, you get the error, which I don't understand.  The symbol `iterator` still has only one thing it can refer to: the typedef in the superclass.  So I guess I have two questions: 1. What do the errors mean?  2.  What is the best way to fix them.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

// #define WITH_TEMPLATE 1

#ifdef WITH_TEMPLATE
template <class C>
struct MyClass : public map<string, C>
#else
struct MyClass : public map<string, int>
#endif
{
    bool haskey(const string &s)
    {
        iterator it = find(s);
        return (it != end());
    }
};

int main()
{
#ifdef WITH_TEMPLATE
    MyClass<int> m;
#else
    MyClass m;
#endif
    m["test"] = 10;    
    printf("%d %d\n", m.haskey("test"), m.haskey("no"));
}
```

Errors from GCC:

> temp.cc: In member function ‘bool MyClass::haskey(const std::string&)’:
>   temp.cc:18: error: **missing template arguments before ‘it’**
>   temp.cc:18: error: expected `;' before ‘it’
>   temp.cc:19: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
>   temp.cc:19: error: **there are no arguments to ‘end’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘end’ must be available**
>   temp.cc:19: error: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)

Comment: Have you tried string::iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your MyClass::haskey method too.

```
bool haskey(const string &s)
{
    typename MyClass<C>::iterator it = this->find(s);
    return (it != this->end());
}
```

Explanation of such a behavior is in section "Name lookup, templates, and accessing members of base classes" on http://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/winter2008/physics141/manuals/rhel-gcc-en-4/c---misunderstandings.html (link from another answer's comment, just in case).

Whole fixed example code: http://ideone.com/G7Rty

Comment: Thanks. I'd mark this as the answer, but it doesn't explain the reason for the error.  That explanation is in a link in the other answer.

Comment: This link is broken or behind a paywall. Any up-to-date references?

Answer (score 3):

```
iterator it = find(s);
return (it != end());
```

This line should be as,

```
#ifdef WITH_TEMPLATE
           typename map<string, C>::iterator it = this->find(s);
           return (it != this->end()); 
#else
           map<string, int>::iterator it = find(s);
           return (it != end());
#endif
```

Comment: @Nawaz so derived class can't see base class typedefs?

Comment: @Ashot: When the base class is a template, the compiler cannot know at parse-time whether or not the class actually contains that typedef or not. Hence, you must use typename explicitly to reference types.

Comment: @Ashot: Not if the base class is dependent on template parameters (i.e., which base class to use can change based on template parameters).  Look at http://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/winter2008/physics141/manuals/rhel-gcc-en-4/c---misunderstandings.html for some information.

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock thanks for explanation. I think this must be added to answer.

Comment: I'll probably mark this as the answer soon, but it would be better if someone can edit and 1. remove the map<string,int>:: from the non-template part.  2. Add the link from Jeremiah or a similar explanation to the answer.   That explanation answered the "why" part of my question.